# Caller save registers in recursion

Tags: assembly, recursion

In recursion, do we need to save both caller save and callee save registers? The following recursion only save calle-save register ebx:

```
int rfact(int x)
{
  int result;
  if (x <= 1)
    result = 1;
  else
    result = n* rfact(x-1);
  return result;
}
```

Assembly:

```
rfact:
        pushl   %ebp
￼￼￼￼
.L3:
movl    %esp, %ebp
pushl   %ebx
subl    $4, %esp
movl    8(%ebp), %ebx
movl    $1, %eax
cmpl    $1, %ebx
jle     .L3
leal    -1(%ebx), %eax
movl    %eax, (%esp)
call    rfact
imull   %ebx, %eax
addl    $4, %esp
popl    %ebx
popl    %ebp
ret
```

Is there any example of recursion that save caller-save register?

Comment: The difference between caller- and callee-saved registers only really matters for leaf-functions. Since a recursive function can't be a leaf-function...

Comment: Hmm, in other words a recursive function is always a calle, that's why it saves only calle-save registers?

Comment: No, a recursive function is always a **caller**. It calls itself. Every function (that is called by anyone) is a callee in that context.

Comment: Then why is no caller-saver registers saved?

Comment: You don't actually need to save *any* register for this function. If you fix your broken C-code and compile with decent optimizations, you'll see that this particular function can be optimized to not use recursion at all.